# High Contrast ON changes icon themes!! How can we avoid this from happening in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: contrast

By doing high contrast to ON, it is changing icon theme automatically.
The changed theme does not look good. Is there a way we can avoid this from happening?
And more surprisingly, when I turn it off, it changes icon them to yet another style which is not good looking either. To regain the original set icon theme, I have to reboot necessarily because Alt + F2 and pressing r to restart the session does not help.

This I ask because I want to make use of High Contrast but I am unable to because it affects icons badly.

Sample icon image for trash when High Contrast is OFF:
[image]

Sample icon image for trash when High Contrast is ON:
[image]

The original theme icon image is not at like any of these. Not posting it because I have to reboot to get it.

If someone has a fix for this, thank you!

Comment: This sounds like something that should be asked [in the Yaru project issues](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues). While there are some members of Canonical who peruse this site, the people answering questions here are generally not the people responsible for the development of, direction of, or decisions pertaining to Ubuntu 

Comment: May be some users may have got a fix for this someway so I posted here. This is the only forum I know which is versatile in Ubuntu questioning. I am editing my question in some time after experimenting now because even reboot is not solving the issue. Also I tried deleting high contrast themes inside icon themes, but it is not solving it either. I will edit this question in sometime soon. Thanks. :) Also are you experiencing this same issue?